# How do I change the background of an Android activity?

Tags: android

I've been trying to change the background color of this activity, if I use true the background is totally transparent but what I want is that the background activity could be seen but a little dimmed.

[image]

```
public class RoundActivity extends Activity {
    Button b1, b2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_round);
        DisplayMetrics dm=new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        getWindow().setLayout((int)(dm.widthPixels*.8), (int)(dm.heightPixels*.4));
        ...
}
```

This is the style I've been using

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="@style/AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="PopUpTheme" parent="@style/NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

In the manifest

```
<activity
     android:name=".RoundActivity"
     android:theme="@style/PopUpTheme">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change by using an image and the put the following in the layout :

```
android:background="@drawable/image">
```

and the image in the drawable. 
If you want to change the color of the background in an activity:

```
android:background="#FFFFFF"
```

The above is for white
I hope this helps!

Comment: That changes the background of the "floating activity", but what I need is to see the background activity(The black background), but with some opacity.

Comment: Do you have your project anywhere up so that I can see?

Answer (score 0):

To change white/black background of your activity use

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/ic_bacground</item>
  </style>
```

as your activity theme

than in your root tag of activity apply overlay that you want